# Cannot get started with Vpython

Tags: python-2.7, vpython

I am a new to python. I am have installed Python27 and Vpython on my windows 64-bit W8.1 laptop.

The python version was **Py27 32-bits and Vpython 32-bits**. After installation I thought I could directly run an **example program** from the **VIDLE** (File -> Open -> bounce). But I realized there is lot more to install to get this working.

So I googled the errors and found that I has to install **Numpy** and **WxPython** which I was able to complete successfully. But now I have this error shown below

"The Polygon module is not installed,
   so the text and extrusion objects are unavailable.
The ttfquery and/or FontTools modules are not installed,
   so the text object is unavailable."

I googled for this but was not able to arrive at anything. 
Should I install Polygon module, FontTools and ttfquery module?

I was not able to fond a proper link to do any of the above. Kindly help me out. I have a hit a wall.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully was able to solve the issue.

The problem was with the way how I installed Vpython. I should have accidentally selected "custom installation" instead of "full installation".

Also the version of numpy that comes with default set-up did not support for me. Hence I used the pip to update the version and now everything is up and running.

I am able to get the example programs to work.

Also the 64-bit version is not working still. So its always safe to stick on to 32-bit version even if your machine is 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

You're working with an older version of VPython that is no longer supported. See the first page of vpython.org.